# White blank screen in custom module production mode magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, layout, frontend

I have created a custom module in Magento 2. In developer mode it is working well, however same module does not show any content in the production mode of Magento its show only white screen. There is no error in logs, apache, system, debug logs are empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: dId you tried `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command? Also check permission when you switch to Production mode.

Comment: Yes i did php bin/magento setup:di:compile but no luck and my controller file has these permission (-rw-rw-r--)

Comment: @MuhammadAyaz how did you solve this, am facing the same issue

Comment: @Daniel_12, I was having issue with the controller. Actually I was using git for version control, however the modified controller file did not update due to some reason thats way I was getting the error at product mode. Once I fixed the controller it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this error myself. In my instance the issue was with the name of the controller file.

The controller file was name `/Controller/Index/index.php`

When it should have been `/Controller/Index/Index.php`

Apparently it worked with a lower case i in developer mode but stopped working in production mode.